# python accessing super class variable in child class

Tags: python

I would like to access the value of self.x in the child class. How do I access it?

```
class ParentClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1,2,3]

    def test(self):
        print 'Im in parent class'


class ChildClass(ParentClass):

    def test(self):
        super(ChildClass,self).test()
        print "Value of x = ". self.x


x = ChildClass()
x.test()
```

Comment: Incidentally, could you edit your error traceback into the question? That would help make this question more relevant for future Googlers, since as it is the issue doesn't have anything to super classes or child classes.

Comment: I think you better mention title as "accessing instance variable of super class from child class". There is a difference between class variable and instance variable in python.

Answer (score 22):

You accessed the super class variable correctly; your code gives you an error because of how you tried to print it. You used `.` for string concatenation instead of `+`, and concatenated a string and a list. Change the line

```
    print "Value of x = ". self.x
```

to any of the following:

```
    print "Value of x = " + str(self.x)
    print "Value of x =", self.x
    print "Value of x = %s" % (self.x, )
    print "Value of x = {0}".format(self.x)
```

Answer (score 11):

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "{} {}".format("First","Last")

class Employee(Person):
    def introduce(self):
        print("Hi! My name is {}".format(self.name))

e = Employee()
e.introduce()
```

`Hi! My name is First Last`